# RAILS, button - ugly strip

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, erb

Moving mouse over this code:

```
<%= link_to pozycja, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Sure?' } do %>
  <button type="button" class="alarm">usuń</button>
<% end %>
```

shows ugly strip wider than the button. I would like to make this work "normally".

Button itself, without `link_to`

```
<button type="button" class="alarm">usuń</button>
```

works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you right. Because of `link_to` you are getting a strip below your text. It's because `link_to` generates an anchor tag `<a>` and because of that you're getting problem. In order to remove that strip you can use `button_to` with that you can easily achieve what you want.

```
<%= button_to pozycja, class: 'alarm', method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Sure?' } do  %>
    usuń
<% end %>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think your explanation is right, but your solution does not work. It generates two buttons.

Comment: Check update. Was in hurry while answering your question so made mistake.